# Where do Passenger logs go?

Tags: phusion-passenger

I have a Rails application running on CentOS with Apache/Passenger, and I have a little problem: I don't have any logs for my Rails Application, What am I missing?

This is my apache conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    Include /home/ftpanel/conf/alias/domain.com.alias
    DocumentRoot /home/mgimmo/public_html/immo/public/

    #Configuration PHP
FastCgiExternalServer /home/mgimmo/ftpanel-config/php5.fpm -socket   /home/ftpanel/conf/sock/mgimmo.sock
    Alias /ftpanel-config/ /home/mgimmo/ftpanel-config/

    <Directory /home/mgimmo/public_html/immo/public/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: Your log should be `/home/mgimmo/public_html/immo/log/production.log`.  Check if that is writeable by the web server user.

Comment: I make a chown on the production.log and yeah it's work ! Why I didn't think that soon ... Can you make an answer then I give u some points :)

Answer (score 8):

Application logs are as usual in log directory under application's root.

In your case, full path is `/home/mgimmo/public_html/immo/log/production.log`

Make sure that file is writable by web server user.